# Prove that probability density function is smooth

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

There is a probability density function that depends on non-deterministic ($v$) and random ($x$) parameters:

$Pr(v)=\int_{G(v)} dP$,

where $G (v)$ is the "goal" region, the probability of getting into it must be determined and that, in turn, depends on $v$ and $x$.
It is known also that the function does not have jumps.

For example, we consider the normal distribution function:

$Pr(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{G(v)} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$

So that:

$Pr(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{G(v)} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} I_{G(x)} (x) e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-2v}^{2v} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$,

where $I (x)$ is the identity function that returns 1 or 0 depending on whether it hits or does not hit $G (v)$, $G (v) = [- 2v, 2v]$, $v = [1,2]$.

MY QUESTION IS: How can I show that this probability function is smooth? I know that to prove it I need to show that it is infinitely differentiable, but I do not see an elegant way to do it.

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: For your example, you can use  $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ is smooth if $f$ is smooth. It is also trivial to check, since the first derivative will give you $f(x)$, which is smooth, then derivatives of all order exists.

Comment: I got it, thank you) But could you please expand you hint a bit and write it like an "answer" so I will be able to vote for it. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to add the solution yourself and other people will upvote it : )

Comment: I have posted my answer - I will be much obliged to you if you take a look at it!)

Comment: I have posted related question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888709/prove-that-probability-function-prv-int-gv-dp-is-smooth I will be much obliged to you if you look at it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hints above I conclude that I should use The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (https://education.ti.com/html/t3_free_courses/calculus89_online/mod16/mod16_lesson3.html) here, which says that If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ has a derivative at every point in $[a, b]$, and the derivative is:

$\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$ (1)

That is, the derivative of the definite integral of the upper limit is the variable. This is true regardless of the value of the lower limit a. The function named F is the same as the area function that was previously explored.

So in my case:

I can take $-2v<=v_0<=2v$ such that:

$Pr(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-2v}^{2v} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-2v}^{v_0} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$

so using (1) we have that:

$Pr(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-2v}^{v_0} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(v_0-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$,

which is smooth, derivatives of all order exists and we can conclude that $Pr(v)$ is also smooth.

Comment: We are taking derivative with respect to $v$, we can rewrite the integral as  $$\int_{-2v}^{2v} f(x) dx= \int_{-2v}^0 f(x) dx + \int_0^{2v} f(x)dx = - \int_{0}^{-2v} f(x)dx + \int_0^{2v}f(x)dx$$ and taking the derivative with respect to $v$, we use the fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule and we will get $-f(v)*(-2) +f(v)*(2)$ .

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks again!!